# Como crio eventos agendados no SQL Server, similar ao "event" do MySQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Em MySQL eu utilizava essa sintaxe para criar um evento agendado:

```
CREATE EVENT 'evento_LimparPaper'
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2014-06-3 00:00:01'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
COMMENT ''
DO BEGIN
UPDATE 'tbl_Paper' SET capa='mudar';
END
```

Porém ao tentar usar estes comandos em um banco SQL Server, aparece que sintaxe está incorreta. Como resolver?

Comment: Por que os votos contrários? Há algum problema grave nessa pergunta que eu não estou vendo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [MySQL Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) é uma funcionalidade específica do MySQL, que não é padronizada pra outros SGBDs (não faz parte do SQL) e, portanto, não pode ser diretamente portada para outras plataformas. Entretanto, há alternativas que fazem mais ou menos a mesma coisa:

1. Considere agendar uma tarefa diretamente no sistema operacional ([crontab](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) no *NIX, [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) no Windows) para executar essas queries. [Há quem considere o SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14805785/520779) o lugar certo™ para isso, e onde os sysadmins normalmente esperam que essas coisas sejam colocadas, mas não posso falar pela experiência...
2. Se precisa de uma solução específica para o SQL Server, veja como funciona o [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189237.aspx). Não tenho certeza se é a maneira mais adequada para esse tipo de tarefa, mas conforme [apontado por Fabricio Araujo nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23283/como-crio-eventos-agendados-no-sql-server-similar-ao-event-do-mysql/23309?noredirect=1#comment43411_23309), seu uso é prática comum na administração de MSSQL.

   [Nessa página](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190268.aspx) (dentro do mesmo tópico) há um exemplo que creio que possa ser adaptado para o seu caso (Nota: ao que me parece, não é só executar o script e pronto; precisa configurar tudo corretamente. Leia a documentação antes de colocar isso em prática):

   ```
   USE msdb ;
   GO
   EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
       @job_name = N'Weekly Sales Data Backup' ;
   GO
   EXEC sp_add_jobstep
       @job_name = N'Weekly Sales Data Backup',
       @step_name = N'Set database to read only',
       @subsystem = N'TSQL',
       @command = N'ALTER DATABASE SALES SET READ_ONLY', 
       @retry_attempts = 5,
       @retry_interval = 5 ;
   GO
   EXEC dbo.sp_add_schedule
       @schedule_name = N'RunOnce',
       @freq_type = 1,
       @active_start_time = 233000 ;
   USE msdb ;
   GO
   EXEC sp_attach_schedule
      @job_name = N'Weekly Sales Data Backup',
      @schedule_name = N'RunOnce';
   GO
   EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver
       @job_name = N'Weekly Sales Data Backup';
   GO
   ```

   Também é possível fazer isso não através de uma query, mas usando o SQL Server Management Studio. Veja as instruções na página linkada. [Essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5471080/520779) mostra um outro exemplo, mais simples.

Comment: Você acha que seria melhor fazer isso no aplicativo. Utilizo C# Web Forms!

Comment: @DiegoZanardo O ideal, como eu falei, seria fazer no próprio SO. Mas se a escolha é entre fazer no aplicativo e fazer no BD, *a princípio* eu faria no BD.

Comment: Tudo bem. Obrigado!

Comment: Discordo quanto ao ponto 1 e o exemplo dos backups. A prática comum em administração de MSSQL é usar o sql server agent,  @mgibsonbr. E quem falou que o backup do banco precisa ser feito com o servidor de bd offline? Backups em SQL Server são feitos ONLINE,  sempre.

Comment: @FabricioAraujo Está certo, foi só um tempo depois de escrever minha resposta que eu percebi que a afirmação original (cuja [fonte](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14805785/520779) eu também me esqueci de atribuir) referia-se ao MySQL e não ao SQL Server. Como o OP está migrando (me parece) de um para o outro, ainda estava com a cabeça focada no primeiro... Obrigado por chamar à atenção ao fato, vou editar a resposta clarificando isso.

Comment: Tranquilo. Eu não poderia deixar passar uma coisa dessas sendo DBA de MSSQL. Hehehe

Comment: Não é necessário colocar um banco para read-only mesmo com centenas de conexões em cima -  basta ter uma janela de menor atividade para o backup